# How to make UITableView load data fast

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

In my app, the tableView data is loading very slowly. I am getting image from JSON for showing it in the `UITableViewCell`.

First, the `UITableView` is empty and only after 15 sec, the data shows up. I want the data to load at the same time when tableView starts loading.

Please give me any idea about my problem. Here is some relevant code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
  NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.educarelive.com/SaveDollar/rest/classifieds/getTestImage"];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    con1=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if(con1)
    {   NSLog(@"Connected");
        webData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"Connected2");
    }
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [secondarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        cell.nameLabel.text = [titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: Please place your code which you have tried/implemented.

Comment: reload your table with Lazy-loading using AFNetworking or SDWebImage Third party class

Comment: @Mrunal now i add some Please give me any idea about my problem

Comment: After you fill in `secondarray` and `titlearray`, you need to reload the table view: `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: @Malloc thanks for Reply  but i already placed [MytableView reloadData]; after second_array and title_array fill

Answer (score 1):

You could use SDWebImage which will make service call in background and let u update the UI(the cell.nameLabel) ,and for ur that image part this will update depending on connection speed. So this way ur user will be able to see nameLabel and image(a bit later - depending on speed of net) and load ur tableView quicker.

Also no need to call reload when ur getting image. SDWebImage code be like this:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
 [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

  cell.nameLabel.text = [titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell;
}
```

Here is link for [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with walle84. And Also u can have UIActivityIndicator while processing Image to Your ImageView.

For this You can use again SDWebImage 's category. And here is the link for this [UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage)